# How can I catch the following obfuscated email addresses in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, obfuscation, email-validation

Consider the following script that contains obfuscated email addresses, and a function that attempts to replace them based with `*****` by using regex pattern matching. My script attempts to catch the words: `"at", "a t", "a.t", "@"` followed by some text (any domain name), followed by `"dot" "." "d.o.t"`, followed by a TLD.

**Input:**

```
$str[] = 'dsfatasdfasdf asd dsfasdf dsfdsf@hotmail.com'; 
$str[] = 'I live at school where My address is dsfdsf@hotmail.com'; 
$str[] = 'I live at school. My address is dsfdsf@hotmail.com'; 
$str[] = 'at school my address is dsfdsf@hotmail.com'; 
$str[] = 'dsf a t asdfasdf asd dsfasdf dsfdsf@hotmail.com'; 
$str[] = 'd s f d s f a t h o t m a i l . c o m';

function clean_text($text){
    $pattern = '/(\ba[ \.\-_]*t\b|@)[ \.\-_]*(.+)[ \.\-_]*(d[ \.\-_]*o[ \.\-_]*t|\.)[ \.\-_]*(c[ \.\-_]*o[ \.\-_]*m|n[ \.\-_]*e[ \.\-_]*t|o[ \.\-_]*r[ \.\-_]*g|([a-z][ \.\-_]*){2,3}[a-z]?)/iU'; 
    return preg_replace($pattern, '***', $text); 
}

foreach($str as $email){ 
     echo clean_text($email); 
}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
dsfatasdfasdf asd dsfasdf dsfdsf*** 
I live at school where My address is dsfdsf@***
I live at school. My address is dsfdsf@***
*** 
dsf *** 
d s f d s f ***
```

**Result:**

```
dsfatasdfasdf asd dsfasdf dsfdsf*** 
I live *** 
I live *** 
at school my address is dsfdsf****
dsf *** 
d s f d s f ***
```

**Problem:**
It catches the first occurrence of "at", and not the last, so the following happens:

```
input: 'at school my address is dsfdsf@hotmail.com'
produces: '****'
should produce: 'at school my address is dsfdsf****'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I guess the obvious question is why are the addresses being obfuscated? If it's deliberately by the users, then any scheme you come up with will be worked around.

Comment: @Douglas, that's fine. Even if they work around it, I'd still like to discourage them.

Comment: Trying to parse natural language with regexp is not the best idea there is just so much nuance that will break whatever you try to build with regexp. This is like trying to parse HTML with regexp.

Comment: @HolyVieR, I'm not trying to parse natural language. I'm trying to parse a very specific pattern. This is not at all like trying to parse HTML with regex, which is wrong for completely different reasons. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: @Colin, I plan to use this for good because spammers use this on my site to scam old ladies. Let's please stick to the problem at hand, and leave your morality or ideas about imaginary usability concerns out of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on M42's regex:

Code:

```
$emails = array(
                'dsfatasdfasdf asd dsfasdf dsfdsf@hotmail.com'
                ,'I live at school where My address is dsfdsf@hotmail.com'
                ,'I live at school. My address is dsfdsf@hotmail.com'
                ,'at school my address is dsfdsf@hotmail.com'
                ,'dsf a t asdfasdf asd dsfasdf dsfdsf@hotmail.com'
                ,'d s f d s f a t h o t m a i l . c o m'
                );

foreach($emails as $email)
{
    $found = preg_match('/(.*?)((\@|a[_. -]*t)[\w .-]*?$)/', $email, $matches);
    if($found)
    {
        echo 'Username: ' . $matches[1] . ', Domain: ' . $matches[2] . "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Username: dsfatasdfasdf asd dsfasdf dsfdsf, Domain: @hotmail.com
Username: I live at school where My address is dsfdsf, Domain: @hotmail.com
Username: I live at school. My address is dsfdsf, Domain: @hotmail.com
Username: at school my address is dsfdsf, Domain: @hotmail.com
Username: dsf a t asdfasdf asd dsfasdf dsfdsf, Domain: @hotmail.com
Username: d s f d s f , Domain: a t h o t m a i l . c o m
```

Answer (score 1):

This a Perl script, could be adapted to php ?

```
my @l = (
'dsfatasdfasdf asd dsfasdf dsfdsf@hotmail.com',
'I live at school where My address is dsfdsf@hotmail.com',
'I live at school. My address is dsfdsf@hotmail.com',
'at school my address is dsfdsf@hotmail.com',
'dsf a t asdfasdf asd dsfasdf dsfdsf@hotmail.com',
'd s f d s f a t h o t m a i l . c o m'
);

foreach(@l) {
   s/(\@|a[_. -]*t)[\w .-]*?$/****/;
   print $_,"\n";
}
```

output:

```
dsfatasdfasdf asd dsfasdf dsfdsf****
I live at school where My address is dsfdsf****
I live at school. My address is dsfdsf****
at school my address is dsfdsf****
dsf a t asdfasdf asd dsfasdf dsfdsf****
d s f d s f ****
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function clean_text($text){
    $pattern = '/\w+[\w-\.]*(\@\w+((-\w+)|(\w*))\.[a-z]{2,3})/i';
    preg_match($pattern, $text, $matches);

    return (isset($matches[1])) ? str_replace($matches[1], "****", $text) : $text;
}
```

The only one this doesn't match is your last one, but you get the point.

Comment: This is pretty good, but I do specifically need to catch the "at" case, and in general the "a t" case (a, any non-aplhanum, t). Thanks for the effort so far.

Comment: The point though isn't to use a straight preg_replace but to actually preg_match and then replace by the index of the match for the second part of the email. So that should at least get your going in the right direction.