# Obscure email addresses in a sentence

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, email-address, redaction

I am outputting log messages and need to obscure the email addresses in them.

A log message might look like this:

```
A lead was saved for sharon.davis@example.com, Date: 11th December 2019, Service: Car Hire ( Premium ), Extras: NA, Price: £300
```

I am using:

```
preg_replace('/(?<=.).(?=.*?@)|(?<=@.).*(?=\.com)/u', '*', $email);
```

I am using this regex to obscure emails, which works great when it's just an email, but in a sentence, it does this....

```
A********************************@example.com, Date: 11th December 2019, Service: Car Hire ( Premium ), Extras: NA, Price: £300
```

Is there a way to only make it go back as far as the space?

So the required result would be:

```
A lead was saved for ************@example.com, Date: 11th December 2019, Service: Car Hire ( Premium ), Extras: NA, Price: £300",
```

Comment: note that a mail address doesn't necessary end with `.com` and **there may be spaces** in a mail address. `this."is a valid".address@mail`

Comment: ok thanks, I didnt know emails could have spaces. ill rethink it.

Comment: How are the logs generated ? Is the content added dynamically with variables, such as mail, date, service, extra, and so on?

Comment: I only have access to the plain text string, not the function that creates them

Comment: this answer could help you => https://stackoverflow.com/a/3345749/12490771

Comment: Try `preg_replace('/(\S+)@/m', '$2********', $sentence);`

Answer (score 0):

If the objective is to obscure/obfuscate email addresses, then don't let anyone know how many characters are being converted to asterisks.

Match the substrings before the `@` and replace them with a static number of asterisks.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ou30X))

```
$string = 'A lead was space" ema il "@emailadds.com saved for sharon.davis@website.com, Date: 11th December 2019, Service: Car Hire ( Premium ), Extras: NA, Price: £300';

echo preg_replace('/(?:[^"\s@]+|"[^"]*")+(?=@[^\s.]+\.)/', '******', $string);
```

Output:

```
A lead was ******@emailadds.com saved for ******@website.com, Date: 11th December 2019, Service: Car Hire ( Premium ), Extras: NA, Price: £300
```